# Serving a Dynamic Image from Flask

Tags: flask

I'm trying to serve an image generated dynamically in PIL from a Flask endpoint.

```
img_io = BytesIO()
image.save(img_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
img_io.seek(0)

response = make_response(img_io)
response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
return response
# return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

I've tried the send_file route, as well as the make_response route. make_response says:

```
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a BytesIO.
```

And send_file says:

```
    return send_file(FileWrapper(img_io), mimetype='image/jpeg')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 640, in send_file
data = wrap_file(request.environ, file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 529, in wrap_file
return environ.get("wsgi.file_wrapper", FileWrapper)(file, buffer_size)
SystemError: <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile> returned a result with an error set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The make_response function, documented [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.make_response), does not take a BytesIO parameter.

It does, however, take a `bytes` parameter, and you can ask for the bytes in a `BytesIO` object using `getvalue()`.

```
response = make_response(img_io.getvalue())
```